# Why fountain fill color changes on rotation

Tags: corel-draw

I use CorelDraw but have an issue regarding fountain fill. I have created a visiting card and given it a fountain fill. I created the visiting card vertically and send to an online printers. They rotated the card horizontally and printed it. When I recieved the printed card, the fountain fill direction was changed. I used a linear vertical fountain fill, but when it was printed (rotated and printed) the direction changed from right to left. Do you know why it changed or how I can lock the fountain fill, or how I can get the same effect when it's rotated.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. In which format did you send the artwork to your printer?  Did you send them a native CDR document or a PDF?  What software did they use to rotate it before printing?  I think this is something you might ultimately have to ask your printer about.

Comment: @BillyKerr I send them in CDR format and they also use coreldraw but the version is different i use 12 older version and they use x16

Comment: I think that you really need to speak to your printer about this. The issue seems to something which they did when altering your artwork. They should have checked the artwork after rotating it, and after making alterations, they should have given you a proof before going to print. In future probably best to send a PDF.

Comment: @BillyKerr they need in CDR format not other format. If i convert in pdf and import in CDR will the fountain rotate?. They also dont have answer for how it happened. I need solution what was wrong or how the fountain rotate.

Comment: PDF's should certainly work in most cases, however if your printer alters the artwork there is no knowing what they might be capable of messing up.  Printers don't usually need source files. Most printers can use PDFs, so I have no idea why they told you that. Again this is a discussion you really need to have with them.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally causes by CTP programs. Because printing firms use your Corel Draw file as PDF which means sometimes some effect may change.

The best solution to get the exact result which you designed is cleaning the effects before sending for print.

In Corel Draw if you follow these steps you can understand what i meant:

1. Go to **File** (Top left of the menu bar)
2. Find **Document Properties** (at the end of file menu)
3. A new window appears
4. In this list you can see everyting about your document

For a great pres result you have to get these results:

1. **Text Statistics:** No text objects in this document.
2. **Bitmap Objects:** All have to be CMYK.
3. **Styles:** No styles in this document.
4. **Effects:** No effects in this document.
5. **Fills:** All have to be CMYK
6. **Outlines:** All have to be CMYK

But it's a long journey to achive these steps. The easiest ways to do these:

1. **Text Statistics:**

   1. Select All: Menu > Edit > Select All > Objects (CTRL+A)
   2. Ungroup All: Menu > Object > Group > Ungroup All Objects (CTRL+U many times)
   3. Select All Textes: Menu > Edit > Select All > Text
   4. Convert All Textes: Menu > Object > Convert to Curves (CTRL+Q)
2. **Bitmap Objects:**

   1. I'm sorry to say there's no exact shortway
   2. But you can just find the bitmap objects like this
   3. Find All Bitmaps: Menu > Edit > Find and Replace > Find Objects (CTRL+F)
   4. Begin a New Search > Next
   5. Choose Bitmaps on the window: Object Types > Other > Bitmaps > Next
   6. Next > Finish
   7. A new windows appears after correct steps. And you can find all bitmaps by clicking Find Next
   8. After found a bitmap you have to start these steps
   9. Menu > Bitmaps > Convert to Bitmap > Resolution: 300 dpi > Color Mode: CMYK Color (32 bit) > Anti-aliasing > OK
3. **Styles:** No styles in this document.

   1. The best way of preparing styles to print is converting items to CMYK Bitmap
4. **Effects:** No effects in this document.

   1. The best way of preparing styles to print is converting items to CMYK Bitmap
5. **Fills:** All have to be CMYK

   1. Replace All Fill Colors: Menu > Edit > Find and Replace > **Replace** Objects
   2. Replace a color model or palette > Next
   3. Find any color model or palette > Replace with the color model: CMYK > Replace colors used as: Fills
   4. Finish
   5. A new windows appears after correct steps. And you can change all the **fill** colors to CMYK by clicking Replace All
6. **Outlines:** All have to be CMYK

   1. Replace All Outline Colors: Menu > Edit > Find and Replace > **Replace** Objects
   2. Replace a color model or palette > Next
   3. Find any color model or palette > Replace with the color model: CMYK > Replace colors used as: **Outlines**
   4. Finish
   5. A new windows appears after correct steps. And you can change all the **outline** colors to CMYK by clicking Replace All

> Before doing these steps you **have to** ungroup all objects in your document
>   If not: you can't achive some steps.

I want to write all the steps one by one but as you can see it's a too long way and it need time :)

Hope that these informations can give you a bit of idea to create a good print file :)
Take care.